# terminal: program input from file

Tags: c, terminal

i have a file "test.txt" which has a list of numbers, like this

```
1
3    
4
2
3
40
312
53
243
321
423
...etc
```

I also have an executable which is a sorting algorithm, for example heapsort.
when i type ./heapsort it asks me for input untill i press CTRL+D.

How can i make that the ./heapsort input is test.txt?

I have a program "generate". so if i put ./generate 20 | ./heapsort it prints the ordered list. How can i make heapsort read from the text file created with ./generate 20 > test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute you program like this:

```
./heapsort < test.txt
```

This redirect the standard input to your file.

Also you may consider change your program to stop asking for inputs after a certain value or when reach the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

on Linux\unix : cat test.txt | ./heapsort